# What is the best prestashop-way to include tpl in AdminController?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need interacts with a .tpl file in my adminController class, but when I try to do that, this error appears

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method RiddlePageController::getCacheId()  in /home/USER/public_html/prestashop/modules/RiddleModule/controllers/admin/RiddlePage.php on line 48

This is my admin controller code:

```
class RiddlePageController extends AdminController {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->html = '';
    $this->display = 'view';
    $this->meta_title = $this->l('metatitle');
    $this->module = "RiddleModule";

    parent::__construct();
}

public function initContent()
{
    $this->postProcess();
    $this->show_toolbar = true;
    $this->display = 'view';
    $this->meta_title = $this->l('Modulo');
    parent::initContent();  
}

public function initToolBarTitle()
{
    $this->toolbar_title = $this->l('Titulo');
}

public function initToolBar()
{
    return true;
}

public function renderView() {
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array( 
            'img1' => "http://www.free-3dmodels.com/image/Flowers-3D-Model-3662994d.png",
            'img2' => "http://www.all3dmodel.com/Images/39.jpg"
            )
        );
    // in return have error "getCacheId"
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'content.tpl', $this->getCacheId());
    // return "<b>This works fine!!</b>";

}
```

my tpl file have only `{$img1}` and `{$img2}` for testing.

Maybe I do all wrong, and this is not the best way to make in my own admin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TheDrot told us, the answer are in using `$this->context->smarty->fetch(location)`, but not in renderList, but in the return statement  of renderView is OK and prestashop get the tpl file and load correctly the smarty variables. Ex:

```
public function renderView(){
    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array( 
            'img1' => "http://www.free-3dmodels.com/image/Flowers-3D-Model-3662994d.png",
            'img2' => "http://www.all3dmodel.com/Images/39.jpg"
            )
        );

    return $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . "RiddleModule/controllers/front/prueba.tpl");
}
```

The file location isn't important to load the TPL file in this case

Answer (score 4):

Your error is because the AdminController class doesn't have the `getCacheId` method.

To answer to your question you have to made some little fix.

First (extends `ModuleAdminController` not `AdminController`):

```
class AdminRiddlePageController extends ModuleAdminController
{
}
```

Then if you want to view your custom tpl, place a `view.tpl` file in:
`prestashop/modules/RiddleModule/views/templates/admin/riddlepage/helpers/view/`
or
`prestashop/modules/RiddleModule/views/templates/admin/riddle_page/helpers/view/` 
(I don't remember well if the underscore is necessary)

And your `renderView` method should be like this:

```
public function renderView()
{
    /* Your code */

    /* Use this snippet to assign vars to smarty */
    $this->tpl_view_vars = array(
        'myvar' => 1,
        'secondvar' => true
    )
    return parent::renderView();
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work my friend... but the good news are with your solution now show the blank page only, no error... let me show you http://prnt.sc/dy8bp5

Comment: @manhattan [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544689/render-helper-form-from-prestashop-admin-controller/) should help you on how to load a custom tpl in an admin controller.

Comment: @manhattan I've made a change, try `AdminRiddlePageController` instead of `RiddlePageController`, don't forget to update the `tab` table in DB

Comment: @sarcom Yes underscores are necessary when the controller name is multiple words camelcased. So `riddle_page` is correct folder.

Comment: @TheDrot Thanks!! your recommendation helped me... but with a little change; in renderView, i returned $this->context->smarty->fetch(ANYWHERE); and this load the file in anywhere location, with smarty variable support!

Answer (score 0):

`AdminController` class has not an implementation of `display` method you use to render TPL.

You can use something like this after set module var:

```
$this->module->display(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->module->name.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->module->name.'.php', 'content.tpl')
```

Good luck.